# Super minor CSS bug when highlighting UserName on some sites in Google Chrome

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

Basically, if you view someone's profile page, and click and hold right on the edge of their username, like if you wanted to highlight their username, but instead of dragging directly to the right, you drag down-ward into their picture, it will cause my [Google Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) browser to move the line of text up (as if there was a line below it that it is trying to highlight;) and this will cause the user name to be cut off, and I think only a page refresh fixes this.

[image: CSS error]

As you can see, it is most noticeable on sites like Stack Exchange site *[Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/9730/garrett-fogerlie)*, that use all CAPS for the username. This doesn't seem to happen here or on Stack Overflow. But it does happen on [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/tour) and probably others.

As I pointed out, **it is practically not an issue**. It may only happen to me (I can't check another browser, because I'm at work (and probably won't care to later). I just figured I'd point it out.

- **Browser:** Google Chrome version 23.0.1271.97
- **OS:** 64-bit Linux Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal Quetzal) derivative;
- **Extra**: Kernel Linux 3.5.0-21-generic, [GNOME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME) 3.6.0

Comment: Heh, that's amusing. I was able to reproduce.

Comment: Reproducible in Safari 6.2 on Mac OS X 10.9

Comment: Reproduced in Chrome on Windows 7 as well, can't make it happen in Firefox though.

Comment: **Reproducedon on a Win7 x64 in:** Chrome v23.0.1271.97m **Can't make happen in:** IE9 (or previous IE browser modes!) **nor** Opera 11.64 b1403 32bit **nor** firefox 12.

Comment: Another way to fix it is to drag select upwards. `overflow:hidden` on `div.subheader` should fix this problem.

Comment: Also not reproduced in firefox on the linux system from the post.