# Add and remove buttons buttons are cut off a bit in Chrome

Tags: bug, design

[image]

It looks like similar issues have been reported, but I'm not sure. Just noticed it ~yesterday but didn't have the time...

---

**Update**

BTW the pick isn't cut off on the right side.. but at the same size as where the other sites  picture adds from above is (at least for my priv level.)

[image]

I haven't noticed it on other sites except this overflow ans this meta... To busy to troubleshoot, sorry.

Did the basics, though on my end... will get back to it if +1reproduced, I have many other VM systems to test on.

**Browser:** Google Chrome Version 23.0.1271.97
**OS:** 64-bit Linux Ubuntu Release 12.10 (quantal) derivative;
 
**Extra** Kernel Linux 3.5.0-21-generic, GNOME 3.6.0

Extra sys info may be found here [Super minor CSS bug when highlighting UserName on some sites in Google Chrome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161913/190311)

---

It looks like, at least for this SO and this Meta, that the buttons have changed and this solved the problem. However, I haven't verified this elsewhere or on a different system.

Comment: Norepro. Windows 7 x64, Chrome (will give version number tomorrow if needed. On mobile)

Comment: Repro Chromium Version 20.0.1132.47 Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit

Comment: Norepro Chrome 24.0.1312.52 m / Windows XP.  Will try to repro on Chromium / Ubuntu later.

Comment: I think it only happens when there is a community bulletin or advertisement above it as shown in the image.

Comment: @AshRj No, it happens even if there is no community bulletin or ad. But it doesn't happen on all sites.

Comment: The same behavior on Firefox on Windows.

Comment: Why does the button not look like this? http://i.imgur.com/n923pEx.png

Comment: @OliverSalzburg because he's old school.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg it does now. It was either a change on SO's side or mine, but now the buttons look like the pic you linked.